# Issue playing local audio file in Discord bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've never used ffmpeg before, and I'm having some trouble with my Discord bot playing a locally hosted and stored mp3 file, of which I own the rights to use. Sadly I am running into an issue where the bot joins the proper voice channel, FFmpeg opens the mp3 file, but no audio is streamed. I have properly set environmental variables, path is proper, there is no error in debugger. Any help would be appreciated.

```py
@bot.command()
    async def play(ctx):
        if ctx.author.voice:
            channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
            vc = await channel.connect()
            vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable='ffmpeg', source='Home_To_You_Cover.mp3'))
        
        else:
            await ctx.send("Please connect to a voice channel first.")
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. 
We are here to help, but our time is valuable and so I recommand you 
to take the time for a [mre]. 
The chances to get an answer are much higher than without. 
If you haven't done yet, [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)
 and read [ask]. In addition I suggest to 
[format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) your question well, 
and you do can check out all of the points in this 
[checklist](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jonskeet/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you didn't the discord.py with voice support, use this pip command to download the package:

```sh
pip install discord.py[voice]
```